# Convergence of bisection method to a zero of $f: [a,b] \to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, bisection

> Let $f: [a,b] \to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(a) < 0 \leq f(b)$.
>
> Show that the bisection method converges to a zero of $f$. That is, show that
> $\bigcap\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} I_{i} = \{x_0\}$ for some $x_0\in [a,b]$ and $f(x_0) = 0$.

I really don't know where to go from here, I've tried using the iterating method for the bisection method, namely:

Iterating the intervals $I_i = [a_i,b_i]$ such that $I_0 = [a,b]$;

And then for every iteration $I_{i+1} = [a_{i+1},b_{i+1}] = 
 \begin{cases} 
      [a_i, \frac{a_i + b_i}{2}], & \text{if } f(\frac{a_i + b_i}{2}) >0, \\
      [\frac{a_i + b_i}{2}, b_i], & \text{otherwise}.\\
   \end{cases}$

After doing this though I have no clue what to do next.

If anyone had advice I'd gladly take it, thanks.

Comment: One idea: show that the length of the intervals decreases to zero, and use the nested interval theorem to show that the intersection of all the intervals is nonempty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [Nested Interval Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_intervals). This tells you that if you have a sequence of nested closed and bounded intervals, where each interval is a subset of the previous one (like in your case), the infinite intersection is non-emtpy, so the intersection you have defined will contain some points.

Now you have to ask yourself, in your case, what points can it contain? Suppose a point $x$ is in the infinite intersection. Either $f(x)$ is positive, it is negative, or it's zero. If if is positive, you should be able to show that *eventually* $x$ will be left out of one of the intervals, and therefore it cannot be on the intersection, yielding a contradiction. If it's negative, you argue in the same way. The only possibility left is that $x$ is such that $f(x)=0$. You can check that specific $x$ will be inside all of your intervals, and therefore also in the intersection.

Note you might also what to think about what happens if $f$ has multiple zeros on the interval $[a,b]$.

*Edited for clarity.*

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. This could be a very stupid question, but how would I go about showing that a $\pm$ x eventually gets left out of the interval?

Comment: Every interval is half the size of the previous one, and every interval contains zero. You could prove than an interval of length $l$ that contains zero can be contained in a closed ball around the origin of radius $l$. Therefore a point that isn't in the ball, is definitely not in the interval. Now assume $x$ is non-zero; eventually $l<|x|$, so the point is not in the ball, thus not in the interval, hence not in the intersection.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help

Comment: I've edited for clarity, bear in mind you work in $[a,b]$ and that the point $x$ in that interval that gives $f(x)=0$ doesn't have to be itself zero. Also, $f$ could have multiple roots on the interval!